# Flutter - readData() from firebase causes the method was called on null

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter with Udemy course called "flutter-firebase-crud-build-2-apps-super-easy". I'm sutck in class number eight to read data from firebase.

My readData() method bellow:

```
readData(){
  DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection("Dishes").document(name);

  documentReference.get().then((datasnapshot){
    print(datasnapshot.data["name"]);
    print(datasnapshot.data["description"]);
    print(datasnapshot.data["price"]);
  });
}
```

is returning this error:

```
E/flutter ( 7077): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7077): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7077): Tried calling: []("name")
E/flutter ( 7077): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter ( 7077): #1      _MyAppState.readData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutterapp/main.dart:52:30)
```

This is my firebase:

[image]

**I can't find the reason of this error. help me please**

Comment: You used **name** where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
readData() async {
var data = await Firestore.instance.collection("Dishes").getDocuments();
data.documents.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
      print("DATA NAME ${documentSnapshot['name']}"),
      print("DATA DES ${documentSnapshot['description']}"),
      print("DATA PRICE ${documentSnapshot['price']}"),
    });
 }
```

Comment: It worked! could you explain your logic to me? thanks

Comment: refer : https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-e6f9e8821b27

see: Retrieve and Display Snapshot

Answer (score 0):

`name` should be `7EwzTZ907d0Fa4N2PfFR`.

When Firestore doesn't find a document, it returns `null`, so `datasnapshot.data` is `null`.